# Amazon EC2 with Windows 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

A new Windows 2k8 R2 image is now available on Amazon. I have two questions about this:

1. It doesn't appear that 32-bit (Small) images are available. Is this correct?
2. From a programmatic point of view, what advantages will R2 give me over the standard Windows image?

Comment: think you need to post this on serverfault as its more a server-admin question than algoritmic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 Windows server 2008 R2 only supports 64-bit architecture. See the system requirements:
http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/system-requirements.aspx

Amazon does not have small instance that is 64-bit, hence why you need to use large or above. And they do not allow you to launch R2 on a micro instance even through micro instances can be 64-bit, probably because of performance reasons.

2 Here is the anser to your second question:
https://serverfault.com/questions/55355/whats-the-difference-between-windows-server-2008-2008-sp2-and-2008-r2

Comment: I've been able to launch R2 on micro - as long as it doesn't have SQL Server, it's fine.